# Optimize simple mysql update query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-update

A simple update query is taking too much time.

I need to optimize this query. There is no join, it should not take that much time.

The simple update query is below:

```
UPDATE need 
    SET `column7` = "in ABC and in", # type: text
    `column9` = "in Abc and in ", # type: text
    `column15` = "", #type: text
    `column32` = "0" #type: tinyint(1)
WHERE id = "36851"


    Field   Type    Collation
--------------------------  ------------------- ---------------
id  bigint(20) unsigned (NULL)
column01    varchar(320)    utf8_unicode_ci
column02    varchar(1024)   utf8_unicode_ci
column03    longblob    (NULL)
.
.
.
.
column32    tinyint(1)  (NULL)
column33    tinyint(3) unsigned (NULL)
```

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

adding more indexes will make **insert** slower not faster, but it will make **select** faster.

Can you list your full table definition?

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem in your table definition. How many rows have you got in your table? what mysql version?

Answer (score 0):

Also an option would be that the database layout isn't very effective for update. 
The Table at all looks quite big, so it would maybe better to split it into different tables, so your update may effect less data...

Your are also able to choose a DB design which fits your requirements best, so if you have a lot of updates choose the BCNF or 4th NF for the layouting. If you have more reads than choose in the best case 3NF which should be mainly the standard normal form od a DB.

All above BCNF has a disadvantage becuase you are loosing FD dependencies so you are going to get more redundancies...

Here a short introduction to NF's:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms